# how to get hour, month from timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

timestamp with timezone is this - `2020-05-31T10:05:07Z`

this is not working, despite referencing official documentation. I need to extract may 2020 or separate month and year to compare against May 2020

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-31T10:05:07Z')


SELECT date_part('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-31T10:05:07Z');
```

Comment: Well, `date_TRUNC` does not extract anything - please define "not working". What do you expect from the first statement and what from the second?

Comment: date_part('day') delivers 31. What are you expecting?

Comment: What do you want to do with the hour part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a timestamp value is "may 2020", you have different options.

```
 to_char(the_value, 'yyyy-mm') = '2020-05'
```

or

```
    extract(month from the_value) = 5 
and extract(year from the_value) = 2020
```

or

```
(extract(month from the_value), extract(year from the_value)) = (5, 2020)
```

---

`extract()` and `date_part()` are the same thing - but I prefer the standard compliant `extract()` version.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d7d0f94f5f1deeddea9de745d2982c0)

You need `to_char()` to format a date or timestamp. `Mon` gives you the first three letters of a month name:

```
SELECT
    to_char(
        TIMESTAMP '2020-05-31T10:05:07Z',
        'Mon YYYY'
    )
```

Returning the entire month name you can use `Month` instead of `Mon`. But, for some reasons, the length of the `Month` value is fixed to the longest month name available. That means `May` is returned with right padded spaces. To avoid this, you need to add the modifier `FM`:

```
SELECT
    to_char(
        TIMESTAMP '2020-05-31T10:05:07Z',
        'FMMonth YYYY'
    )
```